# Creating a short cut to components of an app (Acer Iconia a100 Planner)

Tags: android, shortcut

Can someone tell me how to create a short cut to the sketchboard from the planner app?

I find the sketchpad to be very useful for jotting down quick notes.  However, after you hit all the key strokes to get to it you won't have saved as much convenience as you would if you could got string to it with one stroke.

The acer a100 has a number of workspaces for the user to place his preferred apps.  I would like to place a shortcut to sketchboard in that area.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or comments on this.

-- L. James

-- 
L. D. James ljames@apollo3.com www.apollo3.com/~ljames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press and hold the Sketchboard icon on you apps list for 2 seconds and you will be able to drag and drop the icon on the desktop, you wont be dropping your app, you will be creating a shortcut